# Converting numeric vector to logical based on comparison with limit

Tags: r, type-conversion

I have a numeric variable where values range from ~20 to ~40 and are continuous.

To samples falling below the cut-off (38) I would like to assign `TRUE`, and to all higher numbers `FALSE`. For example,

```
x = c(20, 40, 35, 40)
```

...should result in:

```
c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion for how to do this in R?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 samples <- c(20,40,20,40,38)
 dummyVar <- samples < 38
```

Answer (score 4):

If your data is a vector you can do

`data > 38`

It will give you a logical vector with the information you need.